# Why can't float/double MinValue/MaxValue fit inside a decimal?

Tags: c#, floating-point, ieee-754

Consider the following code:

```cs
float value = float.MinValue;
decimal dec = (decimal) value;
```

> Unhandled exception. System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.

The same applies for `float.MinValue`, `float.MaxValue`, `double.MinValue`, and `double.MaxValue`.

If `float` is 32-bit and `double` is 64-bit, why don't their min/max values fit inside a `decimal` which is 128-bit?

Comment: You know that the max size of a decimal is smaller than the max size of a float? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951834/float-double-and-decimal-max-value-vs-size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [reason](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#characteristics-of-the-floating-point-types) is that `deciaml` is narrower than `float` or `double`.

```cs
// decimal.MaxValue
79228162514264337593543950335

// decimal.MinValue
-79228162514264337593543950335

// float.MaxValue
3.402823E+38

// float.MinValue
-3.402823E+38

// double.MaxValue
1.79769313486232E+308

// double.MinValue
-1.79769313486232E+308
```

Answer (score 1):

As IsakGo pointed out, the `decimal` is narrower than `float` or `double`. This is because `decimal` has much higher precision than either `float` or `double` do. This is why `decimal` is used most for financial applications instead of `float` or `double`.

Because of the precision it has, `decimal` has a narrower range. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types